# proof of existence of the Brownian motion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

I just come about with the definition of Brownian Motion and I'd like to know whether it is not trivial that such a process exists.

Earlier this year, I read about Kolmogorov's theorem and I thought that maybe this could prove the existence of Brownian motion, but unfort. I didn't catch the idea of Kolmogorv's theorem.

So, can one set properties "randomly" on a stochastic process and expect it to exists ?

I also add the folowing question : is such a process unique?

I wasn't that shocked reading about poisson's process. Perhaps, because of the jumps, it feels more natural. On the other hand, Brownian motion seems pretty restrictive and I have no idea how such a process could potentially exists.

---

My definition of Brownian Motion is the following :

1. $$ B_0 = 0$$
2. $$ \text{ stationary and independant increment } $$
3. $$   B_t \sim N(0,t) $$
4. $$ \text{It has continuous sample paths.} $$

Comment: In my stochastic processes classes we discussed two theorems due to Kolmogorov, one that extends "compatible" finite dimensional distributions to a whole process, and one that ensures that a continuous modification exists. The former is called Kolmogorov's extension theorem, as for the latter I have forgotten the name.

Comment: Also you should spell out your definition of BM, there are at least three equivalent definitions.

Comment: good to know. I'm adding mine.

Comment: You need two theorems of Kolmogorov - First is Daniell Kolmogorov theorem, and the second is Kolmogorov continuity theorem

Comment: The process as you have defined it is incorrect (i.e., it is not what people mean when they say Brownian motion). You need the sample paths to be continuous w.p.1., and you need $W_t - W_s \sim N(0,t-s)$ which is more restrictive than $W_t \sim N(0,t)$

Comment: I added the continuous part. I forgot it. What for the second item, I don't know. It is written as I said in the Mikosch, https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=MtQ7DQAAQBAJ&pg=PA35&lpg=PA35&dq=distributional+identity+implies+pathwise+identity&source=bl&ots=f876npDi3j&sig=ACfU3U0ppHmAX2i41ihb9VRk4Xr1MGDT6w&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjInLr4_dLlAhU0XhUIHaWIDxsQ6AEwAXoECBQQAQ#v=onepage&q=Brownian%20motion&f=false. page 33

Comment: @rubikscube09, Nitpicking a little bit, continuity of a stochastic process $X=(X_t)_{t\in T}$ is usually not a measurable property, especially when $T$ is an uncountable space and $X$ is realized as a process in $\mathbb{R}^{T}$ through Kolmogorov Extension Theorem. So it sounds a bit weird for me to say 'sample paths to be continuous w.p.1'...

Comment: You are right of course. The construction of Brownian motion I have done is not through the kolmogorov way but rather through construction of Brownian motion on a countable dense set (say dyadic rationals) and then passing to a continuous extension using uniform continuity.

Comment: Also I've realized I am also wrong when it comes to continuity. That is not needed. Normality implies continuity

Comment: On existence (and on construction) of Brownian motion, I highly recommand you the book from Schilling : Brownian motion, an introduction to stochastic process.

Comment: The covariance definition does not imply continuity; continuity has to be achieved by a modification or by an explicit construction, there is no way to get it out of the finite dimensional distributions.